# Why are my JPanels overlapping?

Tags: java, swing, layout, grid-layout

I am adding more than one panel to a Frame and they are not automatically spacing out. I have a layout manager for each panel. Do I need one for the Frame as well?

The frame is 600X240 and each panel is 200X200. I need the three panels to space out perfectly. How do I force the frame to add one then add the second one where the first ends etc.?

EDIT** 
I added this line of code to my frame's constructor:

```
setLayout(new GridLayout(1,3));
```

and it now works perfectly.

Comment: Could you give us some code to help you?

Comment: The frame's LayoutManager /is/ responsible for spacing out the components for you. You can remove the frame's default LM by calling setLayout(null). Perhaps set a GridLayout, or a BorderLayout, or maybe wrap the panels into a Box.

Comment: I believed LayoutManagers to be specific to JPanels, but now I realize they are used for all components. I added an edit to the OP showing that I did just this. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believed LayoutManagers to be specific to JPanels, but now I realize they are used for all components. I added an edit to the OP showing that I did just this. Thanks!